# I am getting memory leak in my appliaction

Tags: objective-c, memory-leaks, ios4

I am building an application and getting a memory leak problem in a popover.  I hope you can find something.

```
   // Load the SelectWeek value
- (IBAction)loadSelectWeekValue:(id)sender {

    CGRect popoverRectSelectWeek = [self.view convertRect:[selectWeekButton frame] 
                                                 fromView:[selectWeekButton superview]];

    if ([self.productAttributePopover isPopoverVisible]) {
        [self.productAttributePopover dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
    }
    else
    {   
        ProductAttributePopoverViewController* _productAttributePopoverObj = [[ProductAttributePopoverViewController alloc] init];

        _productAttributePopoverObj.dbObject = self.dbObject;
        [_productAttributePopoverObj setFlagVariable:1];
        _productAttributePopoverObj.delegate = self;

        self.productAttributePopover = [[UIPopoverController alloc]
                              initWithContentViewController:_productAttributePopoverObj];
        [_productAttributePopoverObj release];
        self.productAttributePopover.popoverContentSize = CGSizeMake(140, 400);

        [self.productAttributePopover presentPopoverFromRect:popoverRectSelectWeek inView:self.view 
                          permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny 
                                          animated:YES];
    }

}
```

There is problem with popover, can you tell me how to use without allocating!

Yes, I release the the popover and now instrument not showing memory leak but when I perform analyze then it says there is a memory leak.  Please take a look to image and one more issue ""libsystem_info.dylib    si_item_to_addrinfo" this lib causing the memory leak.

http://www.flickr.com/photos/71234685@N02/6794866770/in/photostream/

Comment: You need to add the code around that NSDictionary issue.  Also, how is the tintColor property defining in your header?

Comment: There's no leak in this code. You'll have to post some more, perhaps you can post some that you know runs when the leak appears in Instruments?

Comment: I don't know where this specific dictionary is  used, in the image i post, it says responsible library is "foundation" but no code specific idea?

Comment: This is the instrument code:


# Category Event Type Timestamp RefCt Address Size Responsible Library Responsible Caller
3 UIDeviceRGBColor Release 00:10.534.770 1 0x4e5c200 0 Foundation -[NSAutoreleasePool release]
4 UIDeviceRGBColor Retain 00:10.943.279 2 0x4e5c200 0 UIKit -[UINavigationBar setTintColor:]
5 UIDeviceRGBColor Release 00:10.943.313 1 0x4e5c200 0 TurfNutritionTool -[UINavigationBar(CustomImage) drawRect:]

Comment: Where is the code that deals with NSDictionary?  (And show it to us by editing it into your original post, not putting it in an illegible comment.)

Comment: 1) Have you run Analyzer?  2) In your Zombies run, click on the offending line to "drill down" into the call tree and find where you're (possibly indirectly) calling the problem operation.

Comment: Well, let me try and i will get back to you, Thanks a lot!

Comment: Do you release `productAttributePopover` in your dealloc routine?

Comment: yes i release the the popover and now instrument not showing memory leak but when i perform analyze then it says memory leak, plz take a look to image and one more issue ""libsystem_info.dylib si_item_to_addrinfo" this lib causing the memory leak


http://www.flickr.com/photos/71234685@N02/6794866770/in/photostream/

Comment: My guess is `[self.productAttributePopover = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:_productAttributePopoverObj] autorelease]` - you init it and it never gets a deallocated

Comment: is there any other way to start popover without allocating